# Structure Listing - ridiculous padding

Tags: ee2, structure

I've been asked to resolve an issue on an EE 2.7.3 site with Structure 3.3.14

I didn't build this site and will be recommending an upgrade, however that is not an immediate option.

On the structure page the entire tree has ridiculous amounts of padding between entries. There are no errors in the console. See screenshot.

********** EDIT *********

Turned on structure debug but there is nothing to debug.

[image]

Comment: Does this site have a lot of pages? Is the browser rendering engine actually adding padding to these elements? I get that there is nothing in the dev console but this looks exactly like an issue with JS/CSS loading in Structure. Can you verify you have the right themes for this version of Structure in place?

Answer (score 0):

Often times, this can actually be caused by a different add-on (and often extension). I would recommend backing up the database, and then disabling all other add-ons one by one until you track down what is causing it.